# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'typeorm'

Tags: angular, electron, typeorm

when I try to run the (.exe) file of my electron js project which I developed by angular it gives this type of error how can I fix it?

Comment: did you install `typeorm` correctly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First check you have installed the typeorm as production dependency not as dev dependency .
If the "typeorm" module include any binaries like (.exe,.node) then  electron won't be able to read these binaries in production inside .asar archives. Make sure to exclude the module from packing into asar archives and point to the unpacked directory in production to require the module. Read the issue below it will help. https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/751